# Make a unique duplicate terrain on Unity3D 5.0

Tags: unity-game-engine, duplicates, terrain

I am making a game with Unity3D and I want to have a level prototype which could be copied and modified.

The problem is that when I try this the prototype is also modified.

I have googled how to do it, and the answer (duplicating the terrain data) doesn't work on Unity 5 anymore.

I also tried exporting and importing the heightmap, but it doesn't store textures and trees.

Comment: Heightmap stores height. For those you'd access the Tree Instances and the Alpha Maps via their respective functions in the TerrainData object http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData.html

Answer (score 1):

I found this out on another posting.  I agree most of the answers on Unity forums are not specific enough.

- duplicate terrain gameObject AND duplicate the corresponding terrain data in the project window.
- go to the inspector for the duplicated terrain and enter DEBUG mode.  (this is the big gotcha that is missing from other posts)
- in debug mode, you should see terrain data which is what needs to be updated to the new duplicated terrain data